# How can I access photos from my camera in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, photos, camera, sd-card

I have been trying to compare the speed of importing photos to my Mac from either the camera or by removing the SD card and using a card reader. I have been using the method on question: ["Is there a way to show the speed of copying files on a Mac?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32785/is-there-a-way-to-show-the-speed-of-copying-files-on-a-mac).

Using the card reader I am able to access the location of the files in Terminal, but when I attach my camera (Fuji X-T2) the card is not mounted, I am only able to access it as a camera through applications such as Image Capture, Photos, or Photoshop Lightroom.

Is there a way to access the camera images in Terminal?

Comment: Check out x-bench it won’t use your photos as an example but it uses a wide variety of blank random data to check disk write/read speeds.